# Array to object using Underscorejs

Tags: underscore.js

I have an array with multiple objects,

```
[{Reinvent:24},{Reorganize:18},{Reduce:36},{Reimagine:30}]
```

I am looking for output in the below format only using underscorejs,

```
{Reinvent:24,Reorganize:18,Reduce:36,Reimagine:30}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**_.reduce**](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
var res = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, el) {
  for (var key in el) {
    acc[key] = el[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```js
var arr = [{Reinvent:24},{Reorganize:18},{Reduce:36},{Reimagine:30}];

var res = _.reduce(arr, function(acc, el) {
  for (var key in el) {
    acc[key] = el[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
var result = _.extend.apply({}, data);
```

You can pass any number of source arguments to underscore's [**extend**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function. To take advantage of this we can use Javascript's [**apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function to supply the arguments as an array.

Alternatively you could use ES6's [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var result = _.extend({}, ...data);
```

```js
var data = [{Reinvent:24},{Reorganize:18},{Reduce:36},{Reimagine:30}];

var result = _.extend.apply({}, data);   

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: That's very clever. I will use that from here on out. Thanks!